# How to extract values from multiple rasters and polygons for given coordinates

Tags: arcpy, python, export, spatial-database

I have roughly 30  predictor variables in raster and two polygon shapefiles format that I am trying to extract values from for a given response variable coordinates.

I have already done the following:

1. reprojected all data into same projection (GDA 1994)
2. resampled all rasters to have same resolution

Now my specific question is as follows:

**What function will allow me to extract values from all the predictor variables for given coordinates and output into a .csv file?**

Just to be clear, the following is the output format I need:

X   Y   Insect.Abundance Predictor.1 Predictor.2 .... Predictor.x

My predictor variables are in rasters and polygons. What I want to do is extract a value for each X Y point provided by my response variable. I have not done anything with the polygons besides check for correct projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function to do this in one go.

You need to create a point feature class from your coordinates.  Then use the Extract Multi Values to Points (Spatial Analyst) tool to sample the values for the rasters.  Then use the Spatial Join tool to get the values from the polygons into the point feature class.  Then export your point attributes to a CSV.